# ¿Como mostrar todos los datos del usuario en el SELECT2 a traves de la BD?

Tags: jquery, laravel, select2

me encuentro con un problema en lo que es el llenado de un select multiple para que me muestre todas las opciones seleccionadas para poder editar, para esto estoy ocupando un select2 para realizar esta acción.

A cotninuación dejo el codigo HTML

```
 <select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" name="cboEmpresaCercana[]" id="cboEmpresaCercana" multiple='multiple'>
                        @if(!isset($empresas->idProyecto))
                            @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                                <option value="{{ $empresa->idEmpresa }}">{{ $empresa->nombreEmpresa }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                                <option value="{{ $empresa->idEmpresa }}" {{($empresa->idPropiedad == $traerPropiedad->idPropiedad) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $empresa->nombreEmpresa }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </select>
```

Código JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({});
  });
</script>
```

Me funciona al listar pero, cuando quiero editar el formulario y que me muestre todos los datos que selecciono el usuario no me lo muestra, trae el campo vacio.

Comment: Agregá el código que estás utilizando para levantar la información enviada por el formulario.

Comment: @azeós pues esta en el HTML, solo listo las empresas y las comparo acorde a la propiedad si es igual al iD que seleccione todas, pero queda en blanco la seleccion pero si me lista todas empresas

Comment: Te lista las empresas pero cuando envías el formulario te llega vacío? Si es así, justamente lo que te pido es que muestres el código que _recibe_ el formulario enviado, probablemente el método `update()` o `store()`.